# Why are some meetings in a frame, and others with a plain background?

Tags: calendar

Some meetings in Google Agenda, **coming from the same agenda**, are in a colored frame, while others are with a solid background:

[image]

What is the reason for the difference? Is there a way to fix this to have unified colors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Google Calendar Help](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/7541906?hl=en) says

> **Invitation status**
>
> Events on your calendar look different depending on how you’ve responded:
>
> - If you’re attending an event, the event will be a solid color.
> - If you’ve answered maybe to an event, you’ll see diagonal lines
>     across it.
> - If you haven’t replied yet, you’ll just see the event’s outline.
> - If you said no, you’ll only see the outline and the event will be
>     crossed out.

So, I guess it's the outcome of how you responded to them

Comment: Thank you, I missed that in the help. Since all events are accepted it must be the application which feeds the calendar which does it in an improper way (there is no consistency - some meetings I am invited to and accepted are solid red, some other have just a border, same for meetings I created myself). I will contact Nine's support.