# Accept calendar invite appears tentative

Tags: sync, email, calendar

I'm using BlueMail to manage emails on my phone. Lately, whenever I accept a meeting request for work, my reply to event organizers shows up as tentative.

I'm using Samsung calendar.

Any ideas?

Comment: This may be Blue mail issue. You should write to them

Comment: See this question for similar problem https://android.stackexchange.com/q/187420/131553